# Why is this post on Visual Studio Code formatting locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-posts

*[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode?rq=1)*

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts):

> Also, the system itself will lock posts in certain situations:
>
> - if the post is deleted via "spam" or "abusive" flags.
>
>   - if the post is migrated to another site.
>   - if the post was migrated to the current site, and then rejected.
>   - if a question was merged into another question, the answers will be moved and
>       the source question will be locked.

and:

> Permanent locks should almost never be used, with the exception of those imposed by the system itself. There are two exceptions:
>
> - An extremely popular question which is now considered inappropriate for the site may be locked for "Historical Significance": this alters the appearance of the question, automatically locks all answers as well, and disables flagging completely. This lock should be reserved for cases where a cherished cultural artifact would otherwise be deleted; do not use it for any other purpose.
> - A "wiki" is a question whose answers can be edited by low-reputation users, attributed to multiple authors, and do not grant reputation to the original author. They're occasionally useful in cases where information must be compiled by multiple authors (for example, a list of resources or documentation for the site itself); in these cases, locking the question both prevents it from being closed and prevents further answers from being added.

None of these seem to apply. I can maybe twist my head around to apply the very last rule, but it seems a stretch to me.

Comment: There is a special case of "lock" called a wiki lock which leaves it mostly locked and prevents new answers, but allows editing.  This can be done when you have a quesiton that has been pretty much answered completely but users keep trying to add new answers that just repeat what is already there.  Read more about it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261807/we-should-have-a-question-status-similar-to-locking-that-non-mods-can-set-on-pos/261815#261815

Comment: Context for <10k users: there's 7 deleted answers, several of which are either repeating the existing answers, or are link-only answers.

Comment: Useful Q+A has about 3 answers, give or take.  This one went past useful at a hundred miles an hour and a cop had to pull it over.

Comment: Thanks, all. I can accept either of the first two as an answer, if you want to post one.

Comment: @HansPassant Answers to this question are a bit more diverse than 3 answers, probably because of all the possible combinations of OS and content type or formatting customization that one can expect. May hint that the question is not useful for Q&A, possibly too broad.